# I am trying to create a class which takes values of variables while looping through a textfile

Tags: python, loops, class, object, text-files

''''
I am opening a text file and looping through lines of the file trying to extract info. if a line starts with address i am slicing that line for every thing after "ADDRESS" now there are multiples addresses in the file and each address has specifications like category -Home or office , Residence- code and date registered. I wanna store a object called Address1 with all the properties and then move to the next Address and store them as objects with different name 
I am getting a error that variables Addr , Cate , Resi , date are undefined.
Where am i going wrong please help. i am new to python.
'''

```
handle = open('cibil1p2.txt')
class Adress_data:

    def __init__(self , Address , Category ,Residence_code , Date_Reported):
        self.Address = Address
        self.Category = Category
        self.Residence_code = Residence_code
        self.Date_Reported = Date_Reported
        print(self.Address , self.Category , self.Residence_code , self.Date_Reported)
    def A_data1(self):
        printing = False
        for line in handle:
            line =line.strip()

            if line.startswith('ADDRESS(ES):'):
                printing = True
                continue
            elif line.startswith('EMPLOYMENT INFORMATION :'):
                printing = False
                        # print(line)
                break
            elif printing:
                line.lstrip()
                if line.startswith("ADDRESS:" ):
                    Addr=line[8:]
                elif line.startswith("CATEGORY:" ):
                    Cate=line[9:]   
                elif line.startswith("RESIDENCE CODE:" ):
                    Resi=line[15:]
                if line.startswith("DATE REPORTED:" ):
                    Date=line[14:]   
                    print(line)                    
p1 = Adress_data(Addr, Cate , Resi , Date)                      
p1.A_data1
```

Thank You

Comment: The code sample appears to be incomplete, so we cannot answer this question, can we see the class line and also any preceding code. as it would appear that we are missing a little context

Comment: p1 = Adress_data("bunglow address", "avvfgh" , "vjhbjkb" , "798789")

Comment: @JohnDowling i have updated the post the only missing ting was that handle = open('cibil1p2.txt') and i am looping through this text file

Comment: @JainilPatel I need to take the values from variables defined in the A_data1 defined in the class

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling below line , you have not defined them. 
p1 = Adress_data(Addr, Cate , Resi , Date)

Comment: I do not want to define them, i want values from my A_data1 function .of class Adress_data

Comment: please paste function code as well. You can return values from function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So the reality here is that the line that is failing is the following.

```
p1 = Adress_data(Addr, Cate , Resi , Date)
```

This is because the variables "Addr, Cate , Resi , Date" are not defined in the code examples that you have given.

Your class definition requires these are present.

```
def __init__(self , Address , Category ,Residence_code , Date_Reported):
```

This would mean that you need to pass them from somewhere into your class, or have your class read them from somewhere ie your open statement these would be the two options.

On the face of it, it would seem that your problem is clear, but my gut is telling me the question is not complete or there is a context that is not provided to us that could help us close the gap that you are seeing.

**EDIT 1**

After reading the comments and looking at the code more deeply perhaps you could try the following.

```
class Adress_data(object):

    def __init__(self, Address, Category, Residence_code, Date_Reported):
        self.Address = Address
        self.Category = Category
        self.Residence_code = Residence_code
        self.Date_Reported = Date_Reported
        print(self.Address, self.Category, self.Residence_code, self.Date_Reported)

    @staticmethod
    def A_data1():
        printing = False

        Addr = None
        Cate = None
        Resi = None
        Date = None

        with open('cibil1p2.txt') as handle:

            for line in handle.readlines():
                line = line.strip()

                if line.startswith('ADDRESS(ES):'):
                    printing = True
                    continue
                elif line.startswith('EMPLOYMENT INFORMATION :'):
                    printing = False
                    # print(line)
                    break
                elif printing:
                    line.lstrip()
                    if line.startswith("ADDRESS:"):
                        Addr = line[8:]
                    elif line.startswith("CATEGORY:"):
                        Cate = line[9:]
                    elif line.startswith("RESIDENCE CODE:"):
                        Resi = line[15:]
                    if line.startswith("DATE REPORTED:"):
                        Date = line[14:]
                        print(line)

        return (Addr, Cate, Resi, Date)


    p1 = Adress_data(*Adress_data.A_data1())
```

Comment: I am opening a text file and looping through lines of the file trying to extract info. if a line starts with address i am slicing that line for every thing after "ADDRESS" now there are multiples addresses in the file and each address has specifications like category -Home or office , Residence- code and date registered. I wanna store a object called Address1 with all the properties and then move to the next Address and store them as objects with different name

Comment: I have edited the answer to include what you are saying, please see if the edit helps.